# How can I compile a .pbxproj project through a makefile

Tags: xcode, build, makefile, compilation, gnu

I've downloaded some source code from Apple open source repository.
The projects are .pbxproj files which I can open in XCode.
But I need to export the project to a Makefile/Configure configuration.

I've googled around and found some comments about pbxbuild but could
not find a download link and I'm not sure it is what I need anyway.

Also I tried a tool called pbtomake which failed on the project file.
I guess it's too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pbxbuild` is obsolete - you need `xcodebuild`:

```
$ man xcodebuild


XCODEBUILD(1)             BSD General Commands Manual            XCODEBUILD(1)

NAME
     xcodebuild -- build Xcode projects and workspaces

SYNOPSIS
     xcodebuild [-project projectname] [-target targetname ...] [-configuration configurationname] [-sdk [sdkfullpath | sdkname]] [buildaction ...]
                [setting=value ...] [-userdefault=value ...]
     xcodebuild -workspace workspacename -scheme schemename [-configuration configurationname] [-sdk [sdkfullpath | sdkname]] [buildaction ...]
                [setting=value ...] [-userdefault=value ...]
     xcodebuild -version [-sdk [sdkfullpath | sdkname]] [infoitem]
     xcodebuild -showsdks
     xcodebuild -list [-project projectname | -workspace workspacename]

DESCRIPTION
     xcodebuild builds one or more targets contained in an Xcode project, or builds a scheme contained in an Xcode workspace.

...
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems to compile only xcodeproje. Not pbxproj. Also I don't ant to compile it with a specific tool. I want to export the pbxproj to a standard Makefile architecture. Can I do that with xcodebuild ?

Comment: An Xcode project is a Mac OS X bundle, which is really just a directory with a `.xcodeproj` suffix (e.g. `My_Project.xcodeproj`) which in turn contains several files, the only important one being the `project.pbxproj` file. To build an Xcode project with `xcodebuild` you specify the `.xcodeproj` directory, not the internal `project.pbxproj` file. If you want actual makefiles for other platforms then you'll need to use something like CMake, but that will require some effort to reverse-engineer the Xcode projects. http://www.cmake.org/

Comment: Also, if you have a `.pbproj` rather than `.xcodeproj`, that's an ancient pre-Xcode project which probably needs to be upgraded by Xcode before you can build it.

Comment: Ok so there is not automatic way to generate a Makefile. Too bad. Thanks for the info though.